# Fixed position with long content sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

I have website with long sidebar (content heigher than one browser 'screen'). What I need is:

- when scrolling down the page we also scroll sidebar (as it was static position)
- when bottom of the screen reaches bottom of sidebar we start to drag it (sidebar position fixed to bottom)
- after we drag it for some time, when scrolling up, again scroll it like static position
- when top of the screen reaches top of sidebar we start to drag it up with us until it reaches its sarting point in which it should reamin(position fixed to top)

I've been searching for solutions and also tried doing it with jquery but nothing worked for me. Any suggestions what should I use?

Link: http://savicky.pl/etno/

Comment: So you want the sidebar to scroll independently?  Also, what do you mean by 'drag'?

Comment: I want the sidebar to scroll as normal to the bottom, then follow the user (position fixed, bottom 0 ) while he's reading posts, and when he decides to scroll back to top, scroll sidebar to the top as normal and then follow user to its original position (position fixed, top 0)

Answer (score 1):

I've made you an example. Utilize it! http://jsfiddle.net/QQjTW/

Comment: I added little bit to your response to show what exactly the problem is: [http://jsfiddle.net/QQjTW/14/](http://jsfiddle.net/QQjTW/14/)

Now it's ok when you scroll down, but if you f.eg. scroll to the bottom of the body and start to scroll up I'd like the sidebar to scroll until u can see 'bla bla top' and then set position to fixed with top: 0